# Как можно такой placeholder создать на формах?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу создать такой инпут "placeholder" , то есть звездочка другим цветом в слова другим[image: placeholder]

Answer (score 1):

Label в помощь

```css
#input {
  width: 330px;
}

label {
  color: #aaa;
}

label sup {
  color: red;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  left: -330px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.top {
  z-index: 10;
}

input:focus~label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<label for="input" class="top" id="inputLbl"><sup>*</sup>Контактный телефон с указанием кода</label>
```